# sql where statement with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my WHERE statement I'm trying to find some entities the have BOTH conditions, I cannot use the `IN` statement because it works like `OR` and returning only one result of many, means if I am using:

```
WHERE R.RiskID IN(221,111)
```

So I will get the Documents that have or  111 OR 222
its a problem for me to use the `AND` statement because the proc is dynamic and generates complex code.
example:

```
WHERE R.RiskID IN(111,222)
```

Again, it works like `OR` statement. The defenition table have a row for each `RiskID`, means if I have many `RiskIDs` for same document it looks like:

```
RiskID      DocumentID
111           345
222           345     
333           345
999           846
111           846
```

my final destinations should be, if my input is 111,222 I need to show all the Documents that have 111 AND 222 `RiskIDs`.

Comment: `x in (1, 2)` is just a shortcut for `(x = 1) OR (x= 2)`. there is no equivalent that does `and`. if you want to require ALL (or even 'some') of the `in` parameters to be present, you have to `group` and `count` and `having`, e.g. `select * from foo where bar IN (....) group by bar having count(*) > X`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody have the same problem so the answer is COMBINATIONS and PERMUTATIONS...

`;with list (n) as
(
     select *
     from
     (
     values 
          ('a'),
          ('b'),
          ('c'),
          ('d'),
          ('e')
     ) x(y)
), cte as
(
select CAST( n AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) n
from list c
union all
select CAST( l.n + ',' + c.n AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) 
from cte c, list l
where l.n > c.n
)
select *
from cte`

the generator generates all the possible combinations for the VALUES that in the FROM clouse.

Answer (score -1):

Overkill for the win.  Use this script for smaller query or indexed query.
I have put in the two option, one is to manually define the Riskid or uncomment the sql query to do a wildcard or enter in base on a selection.

```
 Create table #Risk (RID Int Identity,RiskID int)

/* Manual Insert */
insert into #Risk select 111
insert into #Risk select 222

/* SQL insert */
/*
insert into #Risk select distinct RiskID from Tablename where RiskID in (111,222)
*/

Declare @Loop int
set @Loop = 1

Create table #final (RiskID int, DocumentID int)

while @Loop < (select MAX(rid)+1 from #Risk)
Begin
insert into #final
select Riskid, DocumentID
from tablename
where riskid = (select riskid from #Risk where RID = @Loop)

set @Loop = @Loop + 1

End
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using a while loop when simple aggregation would be simpler to write and faster to execute?

Comment: Please present the script that you will have a faster execution on.  I merely show the path, it is up to him to follow.  Which is more than you presented

Comment: No need to be snarky. I didn't think I needed to show a better alternative than a loop since Marc B posted it as a comment.